# T-SQL How does CHANGETABLE Have a Parameter with the Literal Table Name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can pass the literal table name into the built in function [`CHANGETABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql). I was wondering how this is done and if it is possible to do in my own stored procedures/inline functions.

In addition to that. If it is possible to pass it to a literal constant first and then pass it to the function so I can get the table ID and not have to specify the table name in two places.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you want your own stored procedures/inline functions to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is just special syntax**, nothing more. There should be a hint for you in the fact that you are not passing just the table name but also need to put a keyword, either `VERSION` or `CHANGES`, before it. However, even without a keyword it would still be just a syntactic issue.

That is because `CHANGETABLES` is a *built-in* Transact-SQL function, *part of the language*. Of course, one might argue that *user-defined* functions are, in a way, *extensions* to the language. Even so, there is pre-defined syntax for such extensions and it does not include all the variety of built-in functions' syntax. For instance, you still cannot put an `OVER` clause after a UDF, as in window functions, or use `AS` as a delimiter between arguments, as in the `CAST` function, or enforce the argument to be a single string literal rather than an expression, as in `OPENQUERY` or `OPENROWSET`. In short, built-in functions' syntax cannot serve as an example of what you can do in user-defined functions.

The takeaway of the above is, **names still cannot be parameterised in Transact-SQL** without resorting to dynamic SQL.